# Does Fidhiya has to be paid for the missing Fasts of a dead person

Tags: sawm

salam-o-Alaikum,
Respected Brothers, my mother died a couple of months before, she didn't fast for many years because she was disabled from 20 years & because of negligence. so my question is does fidhiya has to be given for the missing fasts of a dead person, even when how many years she didn't fast is not known.
My second question is what is the amount of fidhiya to be paid for not keeping one fast.
jazak Allah-o-Khair